# How to detect in Modernizr if CSS3 selector :target is supported?

Tags: target, modernizr

I'd like to make an off-canvas navigation using CSS3 selector :target but I didn't found any solution how to detect :target support using Modernizr. Does anyone have some ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with "off-canvas navigation"? Take a look at [caniuse:css-selectors](http://caniuse.com/#search=target). It's IMO well supported. Maybe you have another problem? [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): can you give us some context?

Comment: :target is not supported by IE8 and I want to do some fallback for this... About Off-canvas nav you can read here: http://css-tricks.com/off-canvas-menu-with-css-target/

Comment: Oh IE8, I pity you. :) In this case I'd do user agent detection and run a javascript workaround. But I fear missing `:target` support is your least problem. :/

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a `:target` test in [Modernizr v3](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/master/feature-detects/css/target.js)!

This is still in a prerelease though, so you would either have to manually insert it in your build, or build a new one off of http://v3.modernizr.com